# How to convert IntVar to integer in Google OR-Tools

Tags: python, or-tools

```
x1 = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, 'x1')
x2 = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, 'x2')
x3 = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, 'x3')
x = [x1, x2, x3]

def objective(X):
    for i in range (x[1]):
    ...
    return objective

TypeError: 'IntVar' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

It seems that `x1` can not be directly used as an integer for some functions such as `range()`. How to convert IntVar to integer in Google OR-Tools? I need to use `x1` to calculate the objective. Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please provide a **[Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (min-reprex)**, and show us what you want, what you're currently getting, or your current error message, and what you've tried so far, also see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also see [**How to write a perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question)

Comment: Type `dir(x1)` at the python command prompt. You will see the properties and methods of the variable including min and max.

Comment: No, integer variable in the OR context do not behave this way, It particular, this version does not implement a min() or max() method.

Answer (score 3):

You are completely missing the point of declarative programming.

I recommend looking at the structure of a [program](https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/stable/ortools/sat/doc#python-code-samples):

- Declare the variable
- add the constraint
- optionally add an objective
- solve
- read the value of the solution using the solver API

In particular, variables are opaque object that contain a set of possible values. During the solve procedure, this set of possible values is explored until a solution (optimal) is found or infeasibility is proven.

Therefore, you cannot read the value of the variable at any time.